# How to convert a timestamp string containing date and time in this format, to a PHP DateTime format?

Tags: php, datetime

I have a timestamp string which contains date and time in a format like this:

```
$time == "Apr  3, 2015 16:58:46.461897000";
```

I need to convert it to a `DateTime` object in PHP, so that I can perform further operations on it.

Because this format is [not here in the list of supported formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.compound.php).

So the question is that how can I achieve what I need?

I mean the given string contains the date and time in format like **Month-short-name Date, Year Hours:Minutes:seconds**. I need this string to be converted to be **[PHP DateTime object.](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)**

Comment: Do you mean the nanoseconds? If you need that much precision, `DateTime` may not be a good a choice since it only supports up to microseconds.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález No I don't mean the nanoseconds at all. I just need the precision to be up to seconds. I mean the given string contains the date and time in format like **Month-short-name Date, Year Hours:Minutes:seconds**. I need this string to be converted to be [**PHP DateTime object.**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can safely drop the nanoseconds then you can use the *random byte* [format code](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#flash-message) to account for the extra digits:

```
$input = 'Apr  3, 2015 16:58:46.461897000';
$output = DateTime::createFromFormat('M j, Y G:i:s.u???', $input);
var_dump($input, $output);
```

```
string(31) "Apr  3, 2015 16:58:46.461897000"
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-04-03 16:58:46.461897"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Madrid"
}
```

Comment: It's elegant how you avoided `explode()`ing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
<?php

$date=date_create_from_format("M  j, Y H:i:s.u???","Apr  3, 2015 16:58:46.461897000");

echo date_format($date,"M j Y H i s u");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step-by-step procedural php script:

```
// Declare the string
$DateTime_String = "Apr 3, 2015 16:58:46.461897000";

// Convert the string into an array
$DateTime_Array = explode(' ', $DateTime_String);

// Create a new $Time_Array containing one element each for hours, minutes and seconds
$Time_Array = explode(':', $DateTime_Array[3]);

// Remove Hours:Minutes:Seconds element from $DateTime_Array
array_splice($DateTime_Array, 3, 1);

// Concatenate the two arrays
$DateTime_Array = array_merge($DateTime_Array, $Time_Array);

// Convert Simple Ordinal Array into Associative Array
$DateTime_Units = array('Month', 'Day', 'Year', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Second');
$DateTime_Array = array_combine($DateTime_Units, $DateTime_Array);

// Lose the trailing comma on $DateTime_Array['Day']
$DateTime_Array['Day'] = str_replace(',', '', $DateTime_Array['Day']);

// Add a leading 0 to $DateTime_Array['Day'] (if necessary)
$DateTime_Array['Day'] = '0'.$DateTime_Array['Day'];
$DateTime_Array['Day'] = substr($DateTime_Array['Day'], -2, 2);

// Convert Month Shortname into two digit integer
$DateTime_Array['Month'] = date('m', strtotime($DateTime_Array['Month']));

// Build $New_DateTime_String
$New_DateTime_String;
$New_DateTime_String .= $DateTime_Array['Year'].'-';
$New_DateTime_String .= $DateTime_Array['Month'].'-';
$New_DateTime_String .= $DateTime_Array['Day'].' ';

$New_DateTime_String .= $DateTime_Array['Hour'].':';
$New_DateTime_String .= $DateTime_Array['Minute'].':';
$New_DateTime_String .= $DateTime_Array['Second'];


echo '<pre>';
echo '<p>'.$DateTime_String.'<p>'; 
print_r($DateTime_Array);
echo '<p>'.$New_DateTime_String.'<p>'; 
echo '</pre>';
```